# Estimate MLE(parameters) of a distribution from pdf values in the distribution in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have pdf values `[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 ... , xn]` of several points `[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, ....pn]` of a log-logistic distribution.

I want to find out the MLE parameters of this distribution in scipy.
(i.e) `c`, `loc`, `scale`.
Can you suggest a way to do this using scipy library.
Log-logistic function in scipy is `scipy.stats.fisk`

Answer (score 0):

**Method #1: Maximum Likelihood Estimation**

One way you could find the [Maximum Likelihood Estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) of the [Log-logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-logistic_distribution) is by numerical optimization with scipy's [`optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) module.

Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
from scipy import stats, optimize

# Define negative log-Likelihood function
def nll(theta, X):
    return -sum(stats.fisk.logpdf(x,theta[0],theta[1],theta[2]) for x in X)

# true parameters
c, loc, scale = 3.09, 5, 6

# generate artificial data
X = stats.fisk.rvs(c,loc,scale,size=100)

# initial guess
theta0 = [0.1, 0., 1]
# optimization
res = optimize.minimize(nll,x0=theta0,method='Nelder-Mead',args=(X),tol=1e-6)

res.x
```

This will return the found parameter vector `theta`, first entry is shape `c`, second is `loc` and the third is the `scale`:

```py
[2.76583366, 5.43214064, 5.18267233]
```

**Method #2: Curve Fitting**

If you have pairs of measurements `(x,p(x))` and a functional form of your distribution, you can use the measurements to fit the curve. Scipy's optimize module also provides a [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) function.

Here's how:

```py
# wrapper for the fisk distribution
def fisk(x, c, loc, scale):
    return stats.fisk.pdf(x,c,loc,scale)

# simulate (noisy) measurements and randomly sampled locations
X = stats.fisk.rvs(c,loc,scale,size=20)
p = stats.fisk.pdf(X,c,loc,scale) + np.random.randn(len(X))*0.005

# curve fitting
popt, _ = optimize.curve_fit(fisk, X, p)
popt
```

Will estimate the following parameters:

```py
[3.37757066, 4.411966, 6.53535827]
```

Finally a comparison of fitted distribution vs. true distribution:

[image: fitted fisk vs. true fisk]

```py
plt.scatter(X,p,label='data',c='b')
x = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)
plt.plot(x,fisk(x,*popt),label='fitted curve',c='r')
plt.plot(x,fisk(x,c,loc,scale),'--',c='g',label='true cuve')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('p(x)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Final note: The measurements do not need to be noisy. In this case you'd get the true parameter values. But since your `p(x)` most likely come from a histogram, I assume they're not 100% accurate.

Comment: you have used the points you have sampled from fisk (i.e) X = stats.fisk.rvs(c,loc,scale,size=100) to get the parameters. Actually i wanted to find estimates of the distribution if we are given stats.fisk.pdf(X) (i.e) we are given the pdf values of X. Can you help with this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer accordingly and added a curve fitting approach where you have access to `x` values and values of the pdf `p(x)`.